# How to add wildcard character for filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever I use `ate*` my application displays the strings which starts with `"ate"` and similarly whenever I use `*ate` it displays the strings which ends with `"ate"`.

My problem is what needs to be done if I want to display all the strings with `"ate"` by using `*ate*` similar to the output which we get whenever we use 
`"%ate%"`

```
var param = $('#searchvalue').val().trim().replace('*','%');
```

Comment: With no further context your single line of JS isn't enough to diagnose any issues - assuming there even is one as you've not said there's a problem. You've not shown the search logic or anything of relevance. All we can see is the code which turns `*foo*` in to `%foo%`, which works fine.

Comment: This command works fine for *foo and foo* .Its not working for *foo*

Comment: That makes no sense, but I assume it's due to the formatting of comments. Please use backticks to delimit code.

Comment: I don't see how it could work at all considering it'll only replace the first instance of * with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the wildcard globally. Just using `.replace('foo','bar')` will only replace the last occurence. `.replace(/\foo/g,'bar')` will replace *all* of them — for your case `.replace(/\*/g,'%')`